# Conflicting eslint rules: trailing comma vs. the unexpected token

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Question about a project configured with eslint + prettier and stuck with this one for some time now.

Running eslint . --fix on my project updates a file to add a trailing comma, e.g.:

```
server.get(
  '/devices/ventilation/set-level/:level',
  executeSetLevel(domoticz.setVentilationLevel),
);
```

When using vscode afterwards, the editor shows an error about the last line:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token ) eslint
```

Removing the trailing comma removes the above error, but then again complains that I should add the comma back again, resulting in the error above.

My .eslintrc.json looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    }
  }
}
```

And .prettierrc looks like this:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? This problem just crept up with my last npm updating.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/26

Trailing function commas are a syntax error before ES2017.

You can configure `parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 2017 } }` in your config file to allow trailing commas in function arguments.